# How do I use built-in MATLAB functions?

Tags: matlab, ssim

MATLAB has lots of built-in functions that I can call, such as "sin" and "norm." However, some of MATLAB's built-in functions are part of different libraries that I cannot access directly. For example, the function "ssim" is part of MATLAB's image processing toolbox, so I cannot simply call "ssim" in my code and have it work.

How do I call built-in MATLAB functions that are in different libraries? Do I need to import the libraries somehow? If so, how do I do that? How do I do this for ssim specifically?

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you have the toolbox installed, the libraries should be in the path and you can call them directly without importing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Type `ver` into the command window to see which toolboxes belong to the license you bought.

Any function of these installed toolboxes you can call normally, like the mentioned `sin`.

Sometimes, if you're lucky, you can find equivalent functions of otherwise expensive toolboxes at [**MATLAB File Exchange**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/).